# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET

Tags: django

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000

Using the URLconf defined in DjangoAPI.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
^ ^department$
^ ^department/([0-9]+)$
^ ^employee$
^ ^employee/([0-9]+)$
^ ^employee/savefile
^ ^Photos/(?P<path>.*)$
The empty path didn't match any of these
```

Yesterday the Django portion of the project was fine and now I'm getting this error message. I've tried adding `/home/` at the end of `127.0.0.1:8000` and still getting the same thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is most likely in your urls.py, but you should also include your view and your template.

Comment: @Raphael,  thanks for responding. To clarify my thinking I should include the views.py file? When you say template how do you mean? I'm still kinda new pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Yes, at least the view function that leads to the error, the html template file (if there is a link in it, for example, that leads you to this view function), but most important are the root urls.py and the app's urls.py file.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask